# How to define TargetSDK in TestRunner of Robolectric 3.0

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

When using Robolectric 2.4, we could define our testRunner to obtained our AndroidManifest, and defined our getTargetSdkVersion as code below.

```
@Override
protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(MANIFEST_PROPERTY), Fs
            .fileFromPath(RES_PROPERTY)) {

        @Override
        public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
            return TARGET_SDK_VERSION;
        }
    };
}
```

In Robolectric 3.0, this has been changed where we define getting AndroidManifest as below

```
@Override
protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    return createAppManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(MANIFEST_PROPERTY), Fs.fileFromPath(RES_PROPERTY), Fs.fileFromPath(ASSET_PROPERTY));

}
```

This is good. But now, how could I set the getTargetSdkVersion in Robolectric 3.0 now? Note in Android Studio, we don't define the TargetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest. I currently use @Config to workaround it, but would like to put everything in the TestRunner class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```java
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 18) // Here you can change the SDK version
public class MyClassTest ... {

     @Test
     public void testSomething() {
         // ...
     }
}
```

Taken from here 
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1730

**UPDATE**

So I've checked about your last comment and I came up with this, I don't think it's a final answer but I hope at least it give you a hint.

What I did, after reading the Robolectric code I found this

```java
    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
  //  Logger.error("SDK VERSION " + config.sdk());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("sdk", "5");
    Config c = Config.Implementation.fromProperties(props);
   // Logger.error("SDK FROM PROPERTIES " + c.sdk());
   // Logger.error("SDK FROM PROPERTIES " + props.getProperty("sdk"));
    return super.getAppManifest(config);
}
```

All loggers worked and show what I specified but that's where I got stuck. So I tried overriding `createAppManifest` to see if the changes above affected it or not but I don't know how to run this method

```java
@Override
protected AndroidManifest createAppManifest(FsFile manifestFile, FsFile resDir, FsFile assetDir) {
    AndroidManifest an = createAppManifest(manifestFile, resDir, assetDir);
  //  Logger.error("TARGET SDK VERSION" + an.getTargetSdkVersion());
    return an;
}
```

This is quite ugly and hacky, there's must be a better solution. If you ask in robolectric's mailing list you might get a better answer.

Sorry :/

Comment: Thanks Eric. That's what I'm already doing as mentioned in my input above . i.e. "I currently use @Config to workaround it, but would like to put everything in the TestRunner class."

Comment: I'm really sorry, I totally missed that part. I updated my answer. I tried a few things but I don't know how to test if it worked or not (it didn't fail, but I don't know how to test it :P)

Comment: Anyway, if you find an answer please share it.

Comment: I didn't find the answer yet. The simple way to replicate this, is if you have Robolectic 2.4 test, just upgrade your gradle to download the latest version. i.e. testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-rc2'. Be warn though, the new version might not be compatible with your existing test due to much change. By the way, I still "vote 1" for your answer given that other user who are totally lost will still refers to yours as workaround. It's still a feasible workaround, only that for every test, we need to annotate that up. Thanks Eric.

Comment: Just curious, what stopped you from returning the manifest file in 3.0 like you did in 2.4? In both cases the `getAppManifest` returns an `AndroidManifest` object. How does it fail? I'm actually using `org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3` so I wouldn't have problems by upgrading it :P.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and I managed to solve this with overriding getConfigProperties() method. Try this:

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    private static final String MANIFEST = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
    private static final String SDK = "18";

    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties getConfigProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("manifest", MANIFEST);
        properties.setProperty("sdk", SDK);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override method pickSdkVersion in your custom RobolectricTestRunner.